# MySQL full text index doesn't show up in query plan when use with multiple match and related tables

Tags: mysql, full-text-indexing

```
explain

select distinct o.id, o1.id, order_items.order_id
from orders o
    left join orders o1 
        on MATCH(o1.po_number)
            AGAINST('+test*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
        and o1.id=o.id
    left join order_items
        on MATCH(order_items.product_description)
            AGAINST('+test*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)  
        and order_items.order_id=o.id
where COALESCE(o1.id, order_items.order_id)is not null
```

In the above query plan the full text index is not present in the possible keys. Can anyone help with what is wrong here? Thank you.

Comment: Your first LEFT JOIN's ON clause does not specify any relationship between the two tables you're joining. Is that intentional?

Comment: Thanks Jones, just updated it with join

Comment: Any help, please!